# Do users who primarily downvote hurt the community?

Tags: discussion, voting

I think the voting system is great for running a community-moderated forum such as SO, but are users who (almost) solely downvote hurting the community?

To explain where I got this thought, I noticed a user who has:

- 342 Upvotes
- **10,257** Downvotes

That's an average of 30 downvotes to each upvote, and almost 7 downvotes per day since they joined over four years ago.

Users have the right to cast votes how they please, and by no means should they be punished, but this stat makes me wonder what the community's take is on users who primarily vote one way or the other. Certainly someone could say that users who only upvote posts are not doing enough to handle low quality questions.

However, casting nothing but downvotes seems like a very negative attitude that is not beneficial to a website like SO, where users should feel comfortable coming and asking questions.

Should this type of one-sided voting be discouraged? Is there anything we can do other than be self aware and not allow ourselves to fall into that habit?

Full disclaimer, I am *not* (to the best of my knowledge) a victim of downvoting by this user, so this is not some type of revenge, I just happened to stumble upon this profile.

Comment: see [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/165773)

Comment: Votes should _not_ be based on your voting ratio, but on the quality of the post your voting on. If most of what you're seeing are crap questions and answers, well, it stands to reason you're going to downvote a whole lot more.

Comment: `10,257 Downvotes`.  Pffft, amateur.

Comment: Of the 1200ish down votes I've cast on SO, > 50% of those posts have been deleted and a significant amount of the rest closed. I think down voting is *critical* to maintaining quality on the site.

Comment: Bloody hell, I'm a rank amateur.  My vote tallies are almost even!  I'm so embarrassed right now.

Comment: I'll once again point to my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220558/i-am-a-hater-because-people-do-not-understand-voting-patterns-properly/220580#220580 . Looking purely at the number of downvotes someone has cast doesn't really tell you much about their behavior.

Comment: Was it me?  I hardly ever upvote stuff.

Comment: Nah, 2,644 votes.  I'm way behind with  the downvoting:(

Comment: "hurt the community"?  no way!  They are ensuring the good quality content floats to the top!

Answer (score 16):

All votes that accurately reflect that user's view of the quality of the post are helpful.

In my experiences one of the single most beneficial actions that someone can take on the site is to ensure that low quality content is properly indicated as low quality content.  It tends to be *dramatically* more important than having good content be marked as good content (not that that doesn't also have utility either).

So if a user is downvoting that they think is of decent quality out of spite for the author, or just...because, then they're being harmful, just as someone who upvotes content that they don't think it is quality content is taking a harmful action (in fact, I'd say the latter is dramatically more harmful than the former).  If, on the other hand, a user is downvoting a lot of low quality content *that is actually of low quality*, more power to them, they're doing the site a great service.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple answer to this I think.

Users who downvote good questions/answers do some harm to the community.

Users who downvote bad questions/answers do some help to the community.

Comment: Like many simple answers, this is not all that helpful, though it does suggest a sensible direction. One might hope to distinguish good and bad downvotes on the basis of agreement with other votes, but that won't help for moderators more or less blocking spam at the door (see answer to [i-am-a-hater-because-people-do-not-understand-voting-patterns-properly/](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220558/i-am-a-hater-because-people-do-not-understand-voting-patterns-properly/220580#220580)).

Comment: Users who down-vote feature-requests that will help the community? They do harm. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259072/should-there-be-a-grace-period-before-you-can-down-vote-a-post

Answer (score 2):

*Should this type of one-sided voting be discouraged?*

It's may be inevitable that the voting is one sided.

1) It's also easier to tell a question is really bad when you aren't familiar with the language(s)/tool(s) being asked about than it is to be sure a question is good. "Just give me the code" questions look the same no matter what what language they're using (and sometimes they don't even tell you what language they're using).

2) If the question is good; people will stop to try to answer it. If you don't know it off hand that means research, writing code and testing it out, etc. That takes up time. With bad questions the most you'd do is leave a comment explaining why it's bad. Good questions just take longer to deal with.

2b) This means it's easier to take care of some bad questions than to try to answer some good ones if you only have a few minutes to spend on the site.

So I don't think that this happens out of any negative attitude. Bad questions are just easier and faster to deal with.